# AuthenticateAsClient giving RemoteCertificateNameMismatch in ValidateServerCertificate when San not matched with CN

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, .net-standard, san

```
private bool ValidateServerCertificate(
             object sender,
             X509Certificate certificate,
             X509Chain chain,
             SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {}
```

`sslPolicyErrors` is set to `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` when Server Certificate is having SAN different to Common Name.
`ValidateServerCertificate` is called when **AuthenticateAsClient()**  Start the handshake along with server authentication.

> Example: CN: server_cert SAN: DNS:test

But below settings would not give any `sslPolicyErrors`.

> CN: server1 SAN: DNS:server1,server2

Answer (score 0):

TLS client ignores `Subject` field of the certificate when SAN extension is presented. This means that you should connect to a name that is listed in SAN extension, otherwise you get TLS handshake error due to certificate validation failure.

Comment: Where i can find the SAN of the certificate?